# QSystemTrayIcon doesn't show with qasync and aiohttp

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, python-asyncio, aiohttp

QSystemTrayIcon doesn't show with [qasync](https://github.com/CabbageDevelopment/qasync)  and aiohttp, any solutions?

```
import asyncio
import sys
import datetime
from functools import cached_property

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

import qasync
from aiohttp import web


class TrojanGUI(QSystemTrayIcon):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, **kwargs)
        self.setup_server()

    def setup_server(self):
        self.app.add_routes([web.get("/proxy.pac", self.hello)])

    @cached_property
    def app(self):
        return web.Application()

    async def hello(self, request):
        print(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
        return web.Response(text=self.pacContent)  # , content_type='application/x-ns-proxy-autoconfig'

    def startServer(self):
        web.run_app(self.app, port=23336)


def main():
    QApplication.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(False)

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    loop = qasync.QEventLoop(app)
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

    trayIcon = TrojanGUI()
    trayIcon.show()

    trayIcon.startServer()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I don't remember if it works the same also on MacOS and Windows, but at least on Linux if you call `show()` without setting an icon, it won't be shown at all.

Comment: @musicamante Thank you ! Your observation is also right on Windows.

Comment: ok, so the problem is unrelated to async&co, you just didn't set the icon?

Comment: @musicamante Either did not set the icon or the path doesn't exist could hide the QSystemTrayIcon

Comment: Ok. I'd say that your problem is actually not reproducible, also considering that is unrelated to the async matter, since it wasn't caused by it but the fact that the icon wasn't correctly set.